# Caching issue in ngnix

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, nginx

I am stuck at this point, i am hosting a website on amazon aws with the help of nginx server.

this work fine for me until i changed a url, when i changed a url it did not showing, when i hit this url t shows 404 error.
I think this is cache issue in ngninx i tried evey possible available on stackoverflow .

I tried to tuen off sendfile in conf file but there in sendfile line in nginx.conf file
How can i remove cache in ngninx.
Where is this cache directory belongs.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.